# How to rearrange the digits of a three-digit integer (e.g. 978 into this 987) and get the highest integer?

Tags: python

How to rearrange the digits of a three-digit integer so that the highest integer among those three digits is returned?

I tried this:

```
a = int(input('Enter value for a => '))

b = a % 10 
a = a // 10
c = a % 10
a = a // 10
d = a % 10

if (b > c and b > d and c > d):
    print(str(b) + str(c) + str(d))
elif (c > b and c > d and b > d):
    print(str(c) + str(b) + str(d))
else:
    print(str(d) + str(c) + str(b))
```

Comment: 1) The title is not clear. Suggest rewording it to be something like "rearrange the digits in a three-digit integer that the highest integer using those three digits is returned".
2) What have you tried so far, and what was the result? Most Stack Overflow responders are happy to help, but want to see that you have put some effort into solving your problem yourself.

Comment: Thank you @ViennaMike took your suggestions thank you very much for that!

Answer (score 3):

Convert the number to a string so you can turn it into a list containing each digit, sort the list in descending order, join the elements and cast back to an int.

```
def highest(n):
    return int(''.join(sorted(str(n), reverse=True)))
```

Sample

```
>>> highest(192)
921
>>> highest(719)
971
```

**Edit:** If you want to do it by comparing the values of each digit, you don't need to cast it to an int. Just collect the input, and compare each value.

```
a, b, c = input('Enter value for a => ')

if a > b > c:
    print(a + b + c)
elif a > c > b:
    print(a + c + b)
elif b > a > c:
    print(b + a + c)
elif b > c > a:
    print(b + c + a)
elif c > a > b:
    print(c + a + b)
else:
    print(c + b + a)
```

However I believe it's much more tedious to do it this way.

Comment: can you show me with the easiest way like using if elif else? or an other simple starter way?

Comment: There is no need for an if/else statement when you can sort the string in reverse order

Comment: Thank you @alec! This is exactly the help I was looking for! Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Hello at the end this is what I came up with using @alec help.

```
userInput = int(input('Enter three digit integer here =>'))

a = userInput % 10
b = (userInput // 10) % 10
c = (userInput // 100) % 10

if a > b > c:
    print(str(a) + str(b) + str(c))
elif a > c > b:
    print(str(a) + str(c) + str(b))
elif b > a > c:
    print(str(b) + str(a) + str(c))
elif b > c > a:
    print(str(b) + str(c) + str(a))
elif c > a > b:
    print(str(c) + str(a) + str(b))
else:
    print(str(c) + str(b) + str(a))
```

Comment: Let me know if there is a better way of achieving the same with basic code.